# Question from Marker's book T3 has three models up to isomorphism

Tags: logic, model-theory

This question is from Marker's book.

Let $ \mathcal L_3 =  \left\{ {< ,c_0,c_1, \dots}\right\}  $  where $c_0,c_1, \dots$ are constants symbols. Let $T_3$ be the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints with sentences added asserting $c_0 < c_1 < \dots$

Show that $T_3$ has three countable models up to isomorphism.

[Hint: Consider the questions: Does  $c_0,c_1,c_2 \dots$ have upper bound ? A least upper bound ?]

Here I can't see the connection between hint and question and I know the Real numbers and the Hyperreal numbers are models for $T_3$. I need some clue about the hint.

Comment: Three *countable* models?

Comment: @Andres yes thank you

Comment: Can you think of any countable models of $T_3$?

Comment: @ universalset i think raional numbers model of $T_3$

Comment: Right; with what values for $c_0$, $c_1$, $c_2$, etc.?

Comment: they can be any rational with order condition

Comment: Check if there are conditions on whether the order has a minimum or a maximum.

Comment: @andres there are not any minimum and maximum element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  Use a [back-and-forth argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) to show that a countable model of $T_3$ is isomorphic to one of:

- $\mathbb{Q}$, with $c_n = n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
- $\mathbb{Q}$, with $c_n = -\frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
- $\mathbb{Q}$, with $(c_n)$ equal to a particular increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt{2}$ (which particular sequence doesn't matter).

depending on whether $c_0, c_1, \ldots$ is unbounded, has a least upper bound, or has an upper bound but not a least upper bound, respectively.

Comment: It seems interesting but why especially $\sqrt{2} $ at the third one ?

Comment: Nothing special; any irrational number will do.